# Wordpress admin deleted user details not removed in database. How to delete WordPress Users from Database

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

When we delete a user from the WordPress admin panel it's removed, but the user values not deleted in the database.

Anyone let me know how to fix the issue. ?

What is the reason for this issue.?

Comment: That is very strange.. when u delete user from admin panel it should be deleted from db

Comment: No, it's not deleted DB data. I'm using a mutli site.

Comment: Are you talking about regular user values or are they added by a plugin? In which database table are the values?